# Safe way to replace HTML string for exporting to PDF

Tags: c#, html

This is my HTML string:

```
var myHtmlString = '<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Calibri; font-size: medium;">';
```

I want to replace `font-size:medium` with `font-size:16px;` in this string.

I also need to replace other font-size like small or large. You can find the reference [here](https://websemantics.uk/tools/font-size-conversion-pixel-point-em-rem-percent/) for font size conversion.

What is the safest way to replace it?

The reason why I replace it is, I convert HTML string into pdf and export using iTextSharp.

But iTextSharp doesn't support `font-size: medium`. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10260887/9587283)

Comment: Use HTMLAgilityPack. Reference - https://html-agility-pack.net/knowledge-base/8301396/parsing-html-using-htmlagilitypack

Comment: @AnkushJain , can you show an example using AgilityPack ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex on the string:

```
var regexExp = @"font-size\s*:\s*medium";
var myHtmlString = "<span style=\"color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Calibri; font-size: medium;\">";
var htmlStringReplaced = Regex.Replace(myHtmlString, regexExp, "font-size:16");
```

Comment: Better use a CSS parser like [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) instead of Regex.

Comment: Sure thing. I think that it's a bit of an overkill for such a scenario though. Kudos for the suggestion.